# XUL Toolbar is not in FF toolbar list

Tags: firefox, toolbar, xul

Ive got a following problem.

I made a XUL toolbar. Toolbar works correctly, it is displayed correctly and works fine. The only problem is that it is not displayed in the list of toolbars in Firefox. I want it to be in this list - i want to be able to hide/show it from context menu.

What my problem could be in? XUL is organized in following way:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>

    <overlay id="myOverlayName"
      xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
             xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="json.js"></script>
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="md5.js"></script>
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="sd.js"></script>


    <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">
    <toolbar id="somebarid" mode="full" 
        customizable="false" 
        toolbarName="toolbarname" 
    accessibleType="1020" 
    context="toolbar-context-menu" >    
     ...
     ...

    </toolbar>
    </toolbox>

</overlay>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toolbarName="toolbarname"` should :

1) be spelled `toolbarname`

and

2) exactly match `<em:name>toolbarname</em:name>` string in RDF.

After that it works well.